Family Guy episode where Brian is grilled on his knowledge of a band/TV series/movie?
There is an episode of Family Guy that I recall where Brian mentions he enjoys some band/TV series/movie, and someone else starts questioning Brian to see if Brian really knows as much as he claims to know. Brian does not actually know as much as he originally came across as knowing. The scene takes place in a living room if I recall correctly, and Stewie is humorously commenting on the hole that Brian is digging by continuing to pretend he knows a lot about the subject. Can StackExchange help me pinpoint which episode this scene is in?

He tried to bluff his way through a conversation with Stewie about multiversal dimensional physics in "Road to the Multiverse"
